# Which activity method is called when orientation changes occur?

Tags: android, android-activity, orientation, onresume

Which method of the lifecycle is called when orientation changes occur? 
My application executes the `onResume()` method or maybe reloads the whole activity because I've set one boolean to check whether it is first run or not. I've read `onConfigurationChanged()` starts when orientation change occur, is it true? 
How to handle this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ConfigurationChanges

Comment: If i add android:configChanges="orientation", the whole activity will not be restarted, but onConfigurationChanged() will be called instead?

Comment: Remember that you can have *separate* layouts for portrait and landscape - then your activity needs to be recreated/reinflated.

Comment: @Marcin Gil I have a map and i have draw graphics on the users location, but when orientation occurs then the graphics is removed. I want to keep this. I have created reDraw() method which redraws the location, but the app restarts the whole activity...

Comment: See here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Interesting one...

Activity is start `onResume()` is which you declare in your XML by default.

And as I found from question answer on stack overflow is:

## Orientation Change

- onSaveInstanceState
- onPause
- onStop
- onCreate
- onStart
- onRestoreInstanceState
- onResume

## Switch TO Activity 2

- onSaveInstanceState
- onPause

## Orientation Change WHILE IN Activity 2

- onStop
- onCreate
- onStart

## Switchback BACK FROM Activity2

- onResume

I'm guessing that because Activity 1 is hidden at the time of rotation, `onRestoreInstanceState` isn't called because there is no 'view' (i.e., it can't be seen/viewed). Also, it is entirely possible to have 2 completely different layout files for portrait/landscape which potentially have different UI elements with different IDs.

As a result, I'd say if you want to use the Bundle in `onSaveInstanceState` to save your own data, then you need to add extra logic in your `onCreate` (in Activity 1) to process your own data there (as well as doing it conditionally in `onRestoreInstanceState`).

In particular, you could maintain a 'last known' orientation field so that `onCreate` knows that it needs to process your own data because orientation has changed, rather than relying on `onRestoreInstanceState` being called.

Comment: Actually Orientation change = `onPause` -> `onSave...` -> `onStop` -> `onCreate` -> `onStart` -> `onResume`

Comment: Yep, in all cases `onPause` goes first, then `onSaveInstanceState`

Comment: According to android documents, no one can anticipate whether onSaveInstanceState will be called before or after onPause. We can only say with surety that onSaveInstanceState is called after onStop

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: ^^ that's not correct. We can only say that onSaveInstanceState is called BEFORE onStop -> "If called, this method will occur before onStop(). There are no guarantees about whether it will occur before or after onPause()."

Comment: in my case `onDestroy` is also getting called on rotation

Comment: Orientation change = onPause() -> onSaveInstanceState() -> onStop() -> onDestroy() -> onCreate() -> onStart() -> onRestoreInstanceState() -> onResume()

Answer (score 5):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private final static String TAG = "AppActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop() called");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called");
}
```

}

1) Try to run your app on your phone and/or emulator and open the Logcat => on top of the window select Verbose.

2) Now try to change the screen orientation (ex. from portrait => landscape mode).

I hope this alternative will give you more insight into the activity lifecycle.