# After rotation change second instance of service

Tags: android, service, multiple-instances

My app is a video player which streams videos from a nas. Therefore the video is also playing in the background, I have running a startforeground service where the media player is hold.
So every time the activity starts I have to bind to the service, to be able to show the video. This is also required when rotation changed. Then when I want to bind to it, sometimes I don't bind to the already running service but It creates a new instance. So there are two instances of the service.

Yes, normally services should only be able to be instantiated one time, but in my case there are sometimes definitly 2 instances... :/

How can I prevent this? Had anybody already the same problem?

---

EDIT:
service gets started and bound with following code:

> Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class);
>   getApplicationContext().startService(serviceIntent);
>
> Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediaPlayerService.class);
>   getApplicationContext().bindService(serviceIntent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);

Comment: Can you post the method in the activity where you create the object ?

Comment: I have edited and added it to my question ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I wasn't clear because I was interested in which method in the activity life cycle you were doing this in. There are certain methods that are called on-orientation change. This other answer should point you in the right direction.I hope that helps.

[Which activity method is called when orientation changes occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315908/which-activity-method-is-called-when-orientation-changes-occur)

Comment: ah sry. I create my service in onCreate.    
hmm nevertheless instantiating a service multiple times shouldn't be able and there should be a solution. but I will think about the answer you linked.