# Handle Services in orientation change

Tags: android, service, android-lifecycle

I have two services in my app, One for CountDownTimer and one is for Window manager. My main activity is

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Variables


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // some code here

    }



// Broadcase reciever for Countdown Timer
    private BroadcastReceiver br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            updateGUI(intent); // or whatever method used to update your GUI
                                // fields
        }
    };

    private void updateGUI(Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            long millisUntilFinished = intent.getLongExtra("countdown", 0);
            HeadService.textView.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            Log.i("YOLO", "Countdown seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished
                    / 1000);
        }

    }


// Registrating and Starting services in onStart()
    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onStart();
        startHeadService();

        registerReceiver(br, new IntentFilter(BroadcastService.COUNTDOWN_BR));

        Log.i("Check", "Registered broacast receiver");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        try {
            unregisterReceiver(br);
            stopHeadService();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Receiver was probably already stopped in onPause()
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, BroadcastService.class));
        stopHeadService();
        Log.i("Check", "Stopped service");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void startHeadService() {

        startService(new Intent(this, HeadService.class));
    }

    private void stopHeadService() {

        stopService(new Intent(this, HeadService.class));
    }
}
```

When ever I change orientation, My services are stopped and new services start again. So basically what I want to know is where to start and stop my services so it keep running even in orientation change. Also i know what activity life cycle is followed on Orientation change from here [Which activity method is called when orientation changes occur?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315908/which-activity-method-is-called-when-orientation-changes-occur) and I am just not getting what should I do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

onCreate() method is called when you change the orientation of an activity.

To avoid this add the following code to your activity in manifest file :

...
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Comment: Do i need to put this under <activity/> ?

Comment: Awesome, I didn't thought it wold be that easy, Thanks @Hello World :)

Comment: For example :
<application>
<activity android:label="... ..."  android:configChanges= "orientation|screenSize" /></application>